# Error PostgreSQL: RETURN must specify a record or row variable in function returning row

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run these lines:

```
create type _stats_agg_result_type AS (
    count bigint,
    min double precision,
    max double precision,
    mean double precision,
    variance double precision,
    skewness double precision,
    kurtosis double precision
);

create or replace function _stats_agg_finalizer(_stats_agg_accum_type)
returns _stats_agg_result_type AS '
BEGIN
    RETURN row(
        $1.n, 
        $1.min,
        $1.max,
        $1.m1,
        $1.m2 / nullif(($1.n - 1.0), 0), 
        case when $1.m2 = 0 then null else sqrt($1.n) * $1.m3 / nullif(($1.m2 ^ 1.5), 0) end, 
        case when $1.m2 = 0 then null else $1.n * $1.m4 / nullif(($1.m2 * $1.m2) - 3.0, 0) end
    );
END;
'
language plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately I get following error (w.r.t. the `_stats_agg_finalizer` function):

```
RETURN must specify a record or row variable in function returning row
```

Version I'm running:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit
```

I am new to PostgreSQL and I have not been able to fix this error. 
Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I would, but it's out of my hands.

Comment: 9.2 is so old that I don't have a running installation. The code runs on v12. How about playing around with it, like casting the `ROW()` expression to `_stats_agg_result_type` or declaring a `record` variable, assigning to it and returning that?

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind sharing some code snippets please? I mainly interact with PostgreSQL through Python using basic queries - my knowledge is therefore rather limited.

Comment: @sanwall: you might want to show the "powers to be" (who refuse the upgrade) this link: https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.2.24&to=12.2 and ask them why security isn't important to them ;)  (SCNR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was enabled in 9.3.  I assume it corresponds to this [release note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/release-9-3.html):

> Allow PL/pgSQL to use RETURN with a composite-type expression (Asif
>   Rehman)
>
> Previously, in a function returning a composite type, RETURN could
>   only reference a variable of that type.

So you should be able to rewrite it this way:

```
create or replace function _stats_agg_finalizer(_stats_agg_result_type)
returns _stats_agg_result_type AS '
declare f _stats_agg_result_type ;
BEGIN
    f:=row(
        $1.n, 
        $1.min,
        $1.max,
        $1.m1,
        $1.m2 / nullif(($1.n - 1.0), 0), 
        case when $1.m2 = 0 then null else sqrt($1.n) * $1.m3 / nullif(($1.m2 ^ 1.5), 0) end, 
        case when $1.m2 = 0 then null else $1.n * $1.m4 / nullif(($1.m2 * $1.m2) - 3.0, 0) end
    ); 
    return f;
END;
'
language plpgsql;
```

Note that I changed the input type, since you didn't show use the definition of the original type.

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately this raises another error. (If this is related to your last remark, I'm sorry!) I am trying to get following function to work: 
[link](https://github.com/ellisonch/PostgreSQL-Stats-Aggregate/blob/master/pg_stats_aggregate.sql).
The error I get is following `function _stats_agg_finalizer(_stats_agg_accum_type) does not exist`. Any suggestions why? How can I correct this? Thanks!

Comment: Just change the input argument type of the function back to _stats_agg_accum_type.  You will probably have to delete it first, as you can't use OR REPLACE to change the signature.